# Spring DSL: Use message header in transformer

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-dsl

I have xml like below, in the runtime i want to dynamically process . First time first  then  etc

```
<tag1> 
  <tag2> 
.
.
.
  </tag2>
  <tag2>
.
.
.
  </tag2>
</tag1>
```

CASE1: Working code sending static xslt parameter:

```
.transform(Transformers.xslt(this.config.getSome().getXslt(), xsltParameters(1 or 2)))

public Tuple2[] xsltParameters(int number)
{
    final SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    final List<Tuple2<String,Expression>> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

    parameters.add(Tuples.of("Id1", parser.parseRaw(String.format("headers['%s']",ID1))));
    parameters.add(Tuples.of("Id2", parser.parseRaw(String.format("headers['%s']",ID2))));
    parameters.add(Tuples.of("tagNumber", parser.parseRaw(String.format("%d",number))));

    return parameters.toArray(new Tuple2[]{});
}
```

Above is working and transformer can trasnform xslt.

CASE2: Getting error when i want to pass dynamic number:

```
.transform(Message.class, m-> Transformers.xslt(this.config.getSome().getXslt(), xsltParameters())

xsltparametr(){
parameters.add(Tuples.of("tagNumber", 
parser.parseRaw(String.format("headers['%s']",COUNT))));
}
```

ERROR while transforming:

Error on line 158 of test.xslt(Prior to line 158 is working fine)
XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of starts-with() ("xxmmyty", "xxmmyty")

My xslt at line 158

```
<xsl:if test="starts-with(xc:tag1/xc:tag2[$count]/xc:trade/xcml:header/xcml:Identifier/xcml:tradeId[@IdScheme='urn:abcd.something'], 'XYZ')" >
<xsl:value-of select="tag" />
</xsl:if>
```

In CASE1 with same xslt file i can pass above code but in case of dynamic passing(CASE2) it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like you use old enough Spring version.
Would be grate to upgrade at least to `5.0.x`.

Secondly it isn't clear what is your `xsltParameters()`. You hide it from us and we fully don't know what you do over there. Although we can assume that you are fully based on this method:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static XsltPayloadTransformer xslt(Resource xsltTemplate,
                            Tuple2<String, Expression>... xslParameterMappings) {
```

So, you build in that `xsltParameters()` an array of `Tuple2`. OK. So, get access to the header in the param you need to build an appropriate expression.

I'm rally sure that it can be a `FunctionExpression`:

```
.transform(Transformers.xslt(this.config.getSome().getXslt(), 
            Tuples.of("foo", new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(m -> m.getHeader.get("int_val"))))).
```

What you do with the lambda can't be combined with a transformer from that factory.

**UPDATE**

You need to modify your `xsltParameters()` to accept a `String` instead. Which is going to be just raw expression representation.

So, your CASE1 is going to be like this:

```
.transform(Transformers.xslt(this.config.getSome().getXslt(), xsltParameters("'1'")))
```

With meaning as *literal expression*.

The CASE2 is going to be like this:

```
.transform(Transformers.xslt(this.config.getSome().getXslt(), xsltParameters("headers.int_val")))
```

Comment: I tried to give brief about my code. Please have a look.

Comment: For dynamic variant you need to use a mentioned `FunctionExpression` variant to get access to message headers. Or really provide an expression string to you method like this: ` xsltParameters("header[int_val]")`. As I said: what you try to do with lambda for message is not going to work.

Comment: You mean like this- .transform(Transformers.xslt(this.config.getSome().getXslt(), 
            Tuples.of("foo", new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(m -> xsltParameters(m.getHeader.get("int_val"))))))

Comment: No, you don't need to call your `xsltParameters()`  in this case. Or you should change the contract of that method to accept an `Expression` instead.

Comment: I want my case1 and case2 xsltParameters combined to set the xsltParameters required parameters. Could you edit the your answer? I will accept once it is clear.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Same error for Case2 I'm getting. I think we did the same thing in diffrt Way

Comment: i think you still continue to do `.transform(Message.class, m-> Transformers.xslt()` for the CASE2, meanwhile I don't recommend it and I don't show it in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187439/discussion-between-ulhas-n-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: I don't chat here on SO. Please, continue to add comments or modify your question to reflect the current state, but still comment to notify me. Thanks